# Files vanished from SVN working copy - now can't commit

Tags: svn, commit

I'm working on a multi-developer project using SVN. I had a folder with some images in it.

At some point the images vanished despite there being no commit showing them being deleted (I only just noticed when I came to work on the folder). Looking through the commit log I can see that a colleague added them back in and committed the change about 100 revisions ago, but my working copy still didn't have the images, despite updates, checkouts and switching around various revisions.

I manually added the images - but now I can't commit that folder as SVN fails saying the files already exist. I can commit other changes if I ignore the images folder, but this is going to be a pain to do several times a day for the next few years.

Any ideas how I can convince SVN the images don't need to be added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could revert the folder containing the images to a prior commit, which will restore the images (and any necessary .svn folders in the path that are required to track the files).

My guess is that the .svn folder in the images folder got deleted as well, so it looks like the folder is new to your working copy, but the server knows better, since it still has the images in its copy.

Comment: Thanks - the .svn folder is still there. Reverts to various revisions did nothing - no error, no change to folder contents. The images just won't reappear unless I manually copy them back in, but then SVN insists that I add them on each commit, but refuses to commit because I'm adding files that already exist. At this point, I just want to get it to stop bugging me about adding the images on each commit.

Comment: @Hippyjim: If no other edits exist in that folder, I would just delete it and call `svn up` from the parent folder.  Subversion can be a fickle beast

Comment: That fixed it - removing the folder they were in, and updating from the folder above replaced the folder & contents, and SVN is now happy again. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

- Remove all manually-added files
- `svn up` to HEAD

If you will not get all missing files, show log here

Comment: that did nothing - update happened fine - but the files still weren't added - however Dan's answer helped - I had to remove the folder above.